# How to strip leading and trailing spaces of a string in XSLT 2.0?

Tags: regex, xslt, xpath, whitespace, xslt-2.0

How to strip leading and trailing spaces of a string in XSLT 2.0 (with XPath, thus).

`fn:normalize-space` is not a solution because it also collapses spaces inside.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `replace`: `replace('  a  ', '^\s+|\s+$', '')`.